# Kaleo Engine in Liferay: withdrawing/deleting workflow programatically

Tags: liferay

Are there a straight forward solution on how to withdraw/delete a kaleo workflow programatically?

So basically what I wanted to do is that when I delete a custom asset I should also delete the kaleo workflow connected to it. As of now the default behavior, is that when I delete the custom asset there are orphaned data entry on the kaleo tables (like for example in the kaleoinstance table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Liferay are you referring to? I'm looking at the `BlogsEntryLocalServiceImpl` calss in Liferay 7 right now, and I see that when a Blogs Entry is deleted (`deleteEntry(BlogsEntry entry)`), there's a call to `deleteWorkflowInstanceLinks`:

```
workflowInstanceLinkLocalService.deleteWorkflowInstanceLinks(
            entry.getCompanyId(), entry.getGroupId(),
            BlogsEntry.class.getName(), entry.getEntryId());
```

I am guessing you need to call this method in your *LSI class's delete method.

But maybe I misunderstand you?

Comment: Thanks @RussBohi, this is what I wanted :))

Comment: By the way what website, you are looking for the source code for Blogs Entry java class?

Comment: I have the [liferay-portal github repo](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal) forked, but you can also get the source code from [Liferay's downloads page](https://www.liferay.com/es/downloads?559250categoryIds=559255)